Websites assume the wrong country after using a VPN
I used a VPN yesterday (ProtonVPN) that set my location as Japan, and now even though I have quit the VPN and restarted the computer, and the VPN is not running anymore, websites I try to access switch to the Japanese language version.
No matter what browser I use, whether it's a private window or not.
I don't mind too much for now (Japanese ads are way better done than US ads!) but eventually I'd like to be able to revert to my actual location.
How do force my computer to know my actual location?
MacBook Pro 16 Inch, Sonoma

Did you clear your cache and delete your web history?  Those sites might be reading a cookie or something that tells them you prefer the Japanese language.

I found out that the VPN installed a System Settings configuration in the VPN tab that is distinct from the VPN's interface and connects me automatically, I didn't realize it would be on without me having a visual indicator anywhere. It's odd that I can disconnect from the VPN's app and the Settings Configuration would stay on?... confusing

@MicroMachine: That’s bad software design — or a bad bug — and it could have security implications as well! Could you share the name of the VPN software / service?

@EJMak happy to - it's called Proton Software. I will edit my quesiton to reflect my findings

@EJMak posted my own answer and added details in my question if you're interested

@EJMak If you think that's bad software design, look at Global Protect by Palo Alto, used by many big corporations/universities. You can disconnect the VPN but the application will stay persistently open (i.e. show its icon in the menu bar). The only way to actually quit the application entirely is by unloading its launch agent via a launchctl unload terminal command. If you don't unload the launch agent, it will just reopen the application, even if you killed it via terminal/activity monitor. Absolutely ridiculous.

@AVelj the same issue happens if you share your screen on Discord on macOS, even after quitting Discord the menu bar item tells you your screen is still being shared...

That's ridiculous. There's probably a launch agent that persistently stays open. Try entering launchctl list into terminal and see if there's any Discord launch agent/daemon that's listed. If there is, it'll most likely be located in /Library/LaunchDaemons/ OR /Library/LaunchAgents/ OR  ~/Library/LaunchAgents/. Once you've located which of the above directories it is located in, run launchctl unload enter_discord_agent_file_path_here. You may need to run the command using sudo if it is located in /Library/ but if it's located in your user ~/library folder no sudo is required.

I realized after digging in the System Settings that the VPN installed a configuration that has its own UX within Settings.

When one clicks the ⓘ, the "Connect on Demand" option connects the VPN at startup whenever it's activated.

"On Demand" is misleading because once this feature is active, the VPN cannot be deactivated from the System Settings.
Also, the UI of the VPN can state "You are not connected" while the System Settings tell you that you are, at the same time.

However disconnecting from the app disconnects in the System Settings as well.
This behavior and the functioning of the configuration panel as well as the app are irregular. For example, when the VPN is off, and I click on the ⓘ, the "Connect on Demand" setting cannot be modified (the switch moved and becomes blue, clicking OK and reopening the window shows the setting is off again).
I am assuming that my original confusion stemmed from seeing the app tell me that I was not connected to the VPN, and websites loading in Japanese, while I was connected, however at the Configuration panel level in the System Settings.
